# Check any 4 out 10 conditions are satisfied in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize for asking a very vague question but here it is.
I have to write a SQL query in SQL Server as follows.
I have a table say tblA having 10 columns from col1, col2,.....col10.
Each column is not null and definitely holds some value and all of type int.
The query should be to select all such records in which at least 4 columns are matching with given filter criteria, where the filter criteria has values for all 10 columns.

I googled dint get a clue. It needs to be done in SQL server and single query.
Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    yourtable
WHERE
    case col1 when @value1 then 1 else 0 end +
    case col2 when @value2 then 1 else 0 end +    
    ...
    case col10 when @value10 then 1 else 0 end 

    >=4
```

Comment: +1; I got the dreaded "1 new answer has been posted" message as I was submitting.  Looks like we had the **exact** same idea.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables :) I put @s in mine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CASE expressions to determine if four or more columns match:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YourTable
 WHERE CASE WHEN Col1 = Filter1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE WHEN Col2 = Filter2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
     ....
     CASE WHEN Col10 = Filter10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END >= 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             (case when col1 <whatever> then 1 else 0 end) as col01_matches,
             (case when col2 <whatever> then 1 else 0 end) as col02_matches,
             . . .
      from t
     ) t
where (col1_matches + col2_matches + col3_matches . . .) >= 4
```

This creates a separate indicator variable for each match.  You could also do the sum in the subquery, in a single variable.  I would prefer to have each match separately, just in case the logic gets more complicated or I want to see what matches.